# C++ get service network status linux

Tags: c++, linux, networking, service

How can I get in my linux machine the network service status (like service network status in terminal) from C++?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use a call like `exec or execv`. They're available if you include "unistd.h" . For more information on how they work, either look at the man page for exec with `man exec` or [look here](http://www.unet.univie.ac.at/aix/libs/basetrf1/exec.htm):

system can also be used. Like -

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
system("ls -l");
printf("This is a directory list...");
}
```

[you can use iftop command to find network stats in linux.](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iftop)